# Tkinter StringVar Send mail error SMTPlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, smtplib

I am making an Tkinter app to send a short email.

**The code in full:**

```
from Tkinter import *
from smtplib import *
from time import sleep
root=Tk()
root.wm_title("Gmail short message sender")

w = 500 # width for the Tk root
h = 500 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

# set the dimensions of the screen
# and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def send():
    e1_var.get()
    e2_var.get()
    e3_var.get()
    try:
        smtpObj = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', "587")
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.starttls()
        smtpObj.ehlo()
        smtpObj.login("123@gmail.com", "password")
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender1, receivers1, msg1)
        l1=Label(text="Sent").grid()
        sleep(1)
        l1.destroy()
    except SMTPException:
        l2=Label(text="Error").grid()
        raise



e1_var=StringVar()
e2_var=StringVar()
e3_var=StringVar()

sender = e1_var
receivers = [e2_var]
msg = e3_var
sender1 = '%s' % (sender)
receivers1 = '[%s]'% (receivers)
msg1 = '%s' % (msg)

e1=Entry(root, textvariable=e1_var).grid()
e2=Entry(root, textvariable=e2_var).grid()
e3=Entry(root, textvariable=e3_var).grid()
b1=Button(text="Send", command=send).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

**The Problem:**

The problem is with my `StringVar` instances. First the `StringVar` instances were drawing this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Desktop/Python Scripts/Email.py", line 32, in send
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender1, receivers1, msg1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 724, in sendmail
    esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
AttributeError: StringVar instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

But I fixed this by adding this section in,

```
sender1 = sender
receivers1 = receivers
msg1 = msg
```

And changing  `smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg)`  to   `smtpObj.sendmail(sender1, receivers1, msg1)`. I am now getting this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Desktop/Python Scripts/Email.py", line 32, in send
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender1, receivers1, msg1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'[[<Tkinter.StringVar instance at 0x103e8be60>]]': (555, '5.5.2 Syntax error. yi8sm12824416pab.22 - gsmtp')}
```

Is this a syntax error because of the quote marks? If so, how do I fix the first error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (and other code like it) is incorrect:

```
sender = e1_var
receivers = [e2_var]
msg = e3_var
```

You need to change it to this:

```
sender = e1_var.get()
receivers = [e2_var.get()]
msg = e3_var.get()
```

That's not your only problem, though. This code is running before the user has a chance to enter anything, so the results will all be the empty string. You need to wait to call the `.get()` methods until you're ready to use them (which, curiously, you're already doing inside of `send`).